# Unable to create sticky footer based on Bootstraps sticky footer for mobile

Tags: html, css

I am trying to emulate this version of sticky footer done here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sticky-footer/

This is my html code

```
<body>
    @Html.Partial("Navigation/_Navigation")
    <div class="container body-content">
        <div class="content-container">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <footer>
            &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Stardocs Services
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my css

```
html {

}

body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.content-container {

}

/*Footer*/
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

When I view it in desktop mode it sticks to the bottom just fine. However, when I resize the screen, the bar looks like this :

[image]

I'm not sure how to continue from what I've done.

Comment: Will you inspect element on that div so that we could see if there are margins or paddings? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
.body-content { 
  min-height: 100vh; 
  padding-bottom: 50px; 
  position: relative;
}
```

Also, you should remove

```
body { margin-bottom: 50px; }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering but your solution makes it so that desktop view looks like the image I uploaded.

Comment: Then please create a runnable snippet that includes all of the relevant CSS.

Comment: Re-check, please. You need to add `position: relative;` to a parent if you want a child to be positioned absolute inside it.

Comment: Sorry I missed position relative. Thank you.